# Python 2 and 3 co-exist in Windows. How to switch either python 2 or python 3 as default?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Installed python 2.7 in C:\Python27 long time ago. All tools are working with python2. And now I'd like to upgrade it into python 3 in C:\Python3. There are commercial tools like perforce and self-written programs in python that won't work with python 3 automatically. My current PATH is "c:\python27;c:\windows\system32;c:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Perforce;" Working under DOS to validate my tools one by one. Is there a way to quickly switch between python 2 and python 3?

DOS or python scripts

Comment: [Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation) is the de facto standard way to handle multiple Python versions on one machine.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to run both old and new code, but you don't want to change your old code.

So that means when you write some new projects, you may wish to use python3 as default env, but when you run some old project, you still need to use python2.

If that understand correct, the simplest way is to define python2 or python3 when you call your script:

```
# when you want to use python2
python2 test1.py 

# when you want to use python3
python3 test2.py
```

Another way is to install pyenv and set which version of python to use

```
# install Python versions
pyenv install 2.7.18
pyenv install 3.8.12

# set the global Python version
pyenv global 3.8.12

# run your code
python test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you want switch to python 3 and 2 when using
you can using alias (linux)
alias python=<path/to/python/can/use>
exp:
run befor using python2

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

befor using python3

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.7
```

windown use

```
Set-Alias -Name python3 -Value "C:\Python39\python.exe"
```